# Invalid Column Name : SQL / ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, linq

I'm having a hard time debugging a particular problem and have a couple questions. First, here is what's going on:

I have a relatively simple table called `Employees`, which has a primary key / identity `Id`. There is also a `Username` column - which is a `GUID` foreign key to my `aspnet_Users` table used for membership. Finally, there is another foreign key `Team_Id` which points to another table, `Teams`.

All I'm really trying to do is give a selected employee's Id and pass it to a method in the DAL which then finds the employee with the following statement:

```
var employee = entities.Employees.Where(emp => emp.Id == employeeId);
```

Once the employee is retrieved, I want to use another value which is passed to the same method - the selected team's Id - to update the employee's `Team_Id` value (which team they are assigned to), using the following:

```
employee.First().Team_Id = teamId;
entities.SaveChanges();
```

I get the exception

> Invalid column name: {Name}

which doesn't make sense to me, because Employee doesn't have a name column.

All of that said, my questions are:

1. Where could the mix up possibly be coming from? I've tried thinking up a way to step through the code, but it seems like the error is somewhere in the query itself so I'm not really sure how to trace the execution of the query itself.
2. Is it possible that it may have something to do with my generated Entities? I noticed that when I type `employee.First().` `Name` comes up in Intellisense. I'm really confused by that, since as I've mentioned there is no Name column in the employees table.

Comment: Can you show your employee class?

Comment: It's not a class. It's a table in the database. It has an "Id" column (int) a "Username" column (GUID), and a "Team_Id" column (int).

Comment: have you had a column called Name and now it is deleted?

Comment: No, I haven't. Haven't changed anything since initially creating the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue. I just removed the existing Entity Framework Model and re-added it.

Comment: Sometimes that's all it takes - you can always fix things manually, but as long as your model isn't too complex, the old kill-and-recreate method is often the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the query goes, you can always use SQL Profiler to watch what scripts are actually running. That's a good way to troubleshoot generated SQL anyway.

For your property, somehow that did make it to your class, so your data model thinks it's there, for whatever reason. I'd say just go to your data model (you don't mention if this this is EF or LINQ-to-SQL), and you'll see "Name" there. Just remove it, and it will remove it from the class, and from the data access stuff.

Comment: Its using EF. Sorry about that. I'll try removing the Name property and see how that works out.

Comment: Took out everything I could find relevant to the Name property now I'm getting this error: "The number of members in the conceptual type 'Model.Employee' does not match with the number of members on the object side type 'CPM_Data_Layer.Employee'. Make sure the number of members are the same."      Can I re-generate the Entities?